# Guest, User, Moderator, Administrator - vs - User (roles: guest, user, moderator, administrator)

Tags: uml, use-case

Is it better, in modeling web application use case diagram, to create an actor for each role of user can have **or** to have one actor, user and a matrix with privileges?

Guest < User < Moderator < Administrator

### 1: Guest, User, Moderator, Administrator

- Guest: register, reset password, login
- User: edit (self), logout
- Moderator: edit (every user),
- Administrator: manage privileges

### 2: User (roles: guest, user, moderator, administrator)

- User: register, reset password, login, edit, logout, manage privileges

Matrix:

```
                   guest  user  moderator  administrator
register           x
reset password     x      x
login              x
logout                    x     x          x
edit (self)               x     x          x
edit (every user)               x          x
manage privileges                          x
```

---

Which one is better? 1 or 2?

Comment: Your guests can login, but never logout?  Sounds like the Hotel California.  Oh, your number 2 is more flexible.

Comment: `User (guest)` cannot logout when he's not logged in. `User (user)` can logout, and after that, he becomes a `User (guest)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you modeling (like your question says) or implementing?

If you're modeling the use of the web site then you definitely want to think of the different actors and work out what they want (or are allowed) to do. Do that and think about it (make sure people can login and logout as the comments above note). Then use the information you have to do the implementation.

For the implementation you almost certainly want to do it as a matrix of privileges, as it's easier to implement and expand. But you definitely want to put yourself in the shoes of each possible user up front and decide what rights they need/want before going to the matrix.

Comment: My web application uses ACL and role based system. // Approach number 2 (the matrix) is difficult to read (you have to have both: diagram and matrix before your eyes to see who can do what). And approach number 1 is quite easy to understand but hard to maintain (when privileges change).

Comment: But user website can translate from the implementation (method 2) to a readable representation (method 1) easily both to tell users what they can do and to allow editing. Or are you asking how to convert between the two, 'cos that's a different question really.

Comment: The question itself is about modeling. The application itself uses ACL and role based system.